# Удаленная перезагрузка модема Ростелеком

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

Здравствуйте. Цель перезагрузить модем.
Мои действия:

Захожу на веб-интерфейс модема.

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("http://11.11.11.11/login.html")
$ie.visible = $true
$doc = $ie.document
$tb1 = $doc.getElementByID("username")
$tb2 = $doc.getElementByID("password")
$btn = $doc.getElementByID("login")
$tb1.value = "admin"
$tb2.value = "password"
$btn.click()
```

Появился затык. Не могу имитировать нажатие на ссылку. Подскажите как это сделать?

Ссылка: `a onclick="ExpandMenu('admin');" href="#">`

Как еще нажать на кнопку:

```
input type="button" onclick="DoReBoot();" value="Перезагрузить уст-во" style="width: 180px;">
```

Только начинаю изучать `PowerShell`. Поэтому не все получается. Внятно ли объяснил?)

Comment: А не проще ли перезагружать модем через `telnet`? В командной строке пишете `telnet 192.168.1.1`, логинитесь под админской учёткой и выполняете команду `reboot`. Процедура может отличаться для разных модемов, поищите в гугле алгоритм для конкретно вашей модели.

Comment: @fori1ton, Ну вообще-то, как правило, доступ по телнету к роутерам и прочим девайсам ныне закрывают, и считают не безопасными.

Answer (score 1):

Кликнуть в ссылку можно так:

```
$myLink = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('a') | where-object {$_.innerText -eq 'Имя ссылки'}
$myLink.click()
```

Нажать на кнопку с помощью powershell можно так:

```
$myBtn=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | where-object {$_.type -eq "button"}
$myBtn.click();
```